# Caching web View urls data in android

Tags: android, caching

Please I am trying to cache my Web View url data in android. I want to show the cache data in a page when the user's internet is unavailable and show the website data if his/her data is available. I also want to show a message to the user when there is no cache data.

My code below is able to cache the data and show it to the user when his/her internet is unavailable. But I am not able to detect whether there is a cache or not.

```
     if(isNetworkAvailable()){
        view.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
        view.loadUrl(url);

    }
    else{

        // show cache data if cache data exist
        if(view.getSettings().getCacheMode() == WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ONLY){
            view.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ONLY);
            view.loadUrl(url);
        }
        else{
             String summary =
                            "<html><body>"
                            + "<center>Please connect to the internet or check "
                            + "your connection settings.</center>"
                            + "</body></html>";  
                    view.loadData(summary, "text/html", null); 

        }
    }
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: I suggest you to load all data in to local database and than after fetch it is internet connection is not available

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the older Android [CacheManager](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/webkit/CacheManager.java) source code, you'll see the `@Deprecated` annotation with the Javadoc comment:

> Access to the HTTP cache will be removed in a future release.

The method `getCacheFile()` has the `@Deprecated` annotation with Javadoc comment:

> This method no longer has any effect and always returns null.

So I'm convinced you're out of luck with accessing cache information of your `WebView`.

Here are some possible work-arounds:

1. Write a custom `WebViewClient` and override `onReceivedError()`. When page loading fails, you can check show an error message in your application.
2. If the website contains only static files: create an archive of it and sync it with your device and load it only locally